# Prove that all bounded decreasing monetone sequences converge. (I need a hint)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove all bounded monotone sequence converge.

I just need a hint.

Let $k_n$ be a bounded decreasing sequence. Let $K$ denote the set $\{ k_n : k \in \mathbb N\}$ and let $g = \inf K$. Since $K$ is bounded, $g$ represents a real number. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because $g + \epsilon$ is not a lower bounded for $K$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $k_N < g + \epsilon$. Now I'm stuck. Do I claim that $k_N < g$ which implies $N < n$? I need a hint.

Comment: Can you explain what is $k_n$ and $s_n$?

Comment: $k_n$ is the sequence. $s_n$ is a typo on my part. Our professor keeps using $k_n$ my textbook uses $s_n$

Comment: Ok. Now try to use the fact that $k_n$ is decreasing. You should get $g\le k_n \le g+\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. (You cannot get $k_N < g$ as $g$ is a lower bound of $K$)

Comment: I'm confused. Where'd  g≤kn≤g+ϵ come from?

Comment: Let split into two cases. First do you know why $g \le k_n$ (Think of what is  $g$)?

Comment: I'm not sure what glekn is.

Comment: Sorry I mean $g \le k_n$.

Comment: So g is our greatest lower bound. The greatest lower bound means that for all values of k in our set, g is strictly less than or equal to k. Also if there is a lower bound, (denote it a), a will be strictly less than or equal to g.

Comment: In particular, $g$ is a lower bound of $K$, so $g\le k_n$ for all $k_n \in K$.

Comment: Then g≤kn<g+ϵ.
Which implies (from algebraic manipulation) 0 ≤kn - g<ϵ. Then by the def of abs value. kn - g≤|kn - g|<ϵ.

Comment: You have already $k_N < g+ \epsilon$ for a fixed $N$, how do you know that $k_n < g+ \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$?

Comment: Does this come from the fact that n > N implies sn < sN. This comes from the definition of a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Yes. Perfect. So you have $g\le k_n < g+ \epsilon$. You are almost done.

Comment: Then g≤kn≤kN<g+ϵ. Which implies (from algebraic manipulation) 0 ≤kn - g<ϵ. Then by the def of abs value. kn - g≤|kn - g|<ϵ.

Comment: Perfect. You are done.